# how to check that when a text file exists, a certain txtfield will equal to the last data entered?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

this is my code when the jframe loads...

```
try {
    File file = new File("D:\\CedulaList.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //stringBuffer.append(line);
        //stringBuffer.append("\n");

                String[] dataArray = line.split(",");

                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableCedula.getModel();
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
                model.addRow(new Object[]{

                    dataArray[0],
                    dataArray[1],
                    dataArray[2],
                    dataArray[3],
                    dataArray[4],
                    dataArray[5],
                    dataArray[6],
                    dataArray[7],
                    dataArray[8],
                    dataArray[9],
                    dataArray[10],
                    dataArray[11]

                } );
            loadCed = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[0]);    
    }
            txtCedNum.setText(Integer.toString(loadCed + 1));
    fileReader.close();

            //stringBuffer.toString() //para get txtfile input

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

also, in the topmost portion of the entire code, i have set loadCed to 0 by way of int.

my problem is that when the text file exists but is empty the txtCedNum is set to 1. i wish for it to be set to 543210, and then increments when i add data to the jtable.

second problem is that when the text file does not exist on the path, txtCedNum is set to blank. again i wish for it to be set to 543210 and then increments when i add data to the jtable.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.